# How do i make a program that makes automated candy packs and a list of the items it added in Python?

Tags: python, calculation, price

So hello, i am trying to make a program that makes candy packs automatically. How i want it to work is basically use a `while` loop . You set a wished price as a Float number and the program picks out random items from a list until the select price is full or a little overboard. After that i want it to add the names of the items it picked in a list. The aproach i tried was making a list of every item and element "0" contains the price and element "1" contains the name. So basically when im adding the price to the "Price" variable im picking element "0" and when i append it to the "selected items" list i append the element "1"

here is the code i came up with so far

```
print("hello World")
from random import randint

cheapCandy = [0.04, "cheap Candy"]
candyPack = [0.16, "candy Pack"]
mentosPack = [0.49, "mentos Gum"]
smallChocolate = [0.4, "small Chocolate"]

items = [cheapCandy, candyPack, mentosPack, smallChocolate]
selected = []


e = int(input("price range do you want?"))
price = 0
float(price)
while price < e:
    i = randint(0,len(items)-1)
    price += items[i[0]]
    selected.append(items[i[1]])
print("your total worth of items is", price, "4")

print("and you can sell that for around", price + 1, "$, or", price+1.5, "$")
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Replace with these lines to have a working starting program `price += items[i][0]
selected.append(items[i][1])`

Answer (score 1):

the error was here:

```
price += items[i[0]]
selected.append(items[i[1]])
```

so you can change those lines to this:

```
price += items[i][0]
selected.append(items[i][1])
```

i also recomend you to use `f format` strings. Like this:

```
print(f"your total worth of items is {price} 4")
print(f"and you can sell that for around {price + 1}$, or {price + 1.5}$")
```

here is some link to the f-format strings: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/